# what's the unknow service in Istio Kiali?

Tags: istio, kiali

It's quite strange to see there's "unknown" service(marked with red box) going out from "fota-dmserver". Could you help explain?
[image: kiali admin console]

Answer (score 0):

A service displayed as "Unknown" can be pretty much anything that is not part of the service mesh. It has such a name in Kiali because this service was not declared, so Istio / Kiali have no idea about what it is. It could be, for instance, calls to third party APIs. To declare it, you must use a Service Entry: https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/service-entry/ .

If you have no idea what it is you should investigate client calls performed from your `fota-dmserver` service.

Comment: the calls from "fota-dmserver" to the services outside of mesh- redis server, mysql DB. "fota-car" service has similiar situation with "fota-dmserver". My question why there's no link from "fota-car" to "unknown"? I'm really curious.

Comment: As you describe, there should be. Might be an indication that not everything is working as you expect in your mesh? Or might be a problem on istio/kiali side as well. I guess it deserves more investigation on your side... FYI Kiali shows what telemetry is available in Prometheus, so if you want to see if Kiali is missing something, you could check Prometheus metric "istio_requests_total" with "fota-car" as source and check what are the destination services (and if there's "unknown"). You can do that from the Prometheus console.

Comment: @YoufaMao do you see the same issue if you switch graph view to "Workload graph" ?